Is there any way to prevent mongod from using all of the RAM?
Hope the following stuff below is self-explanatory.
The only question is WHY.
Spent the whole day reading technical stuff, seems like MongoDB becomes more and more "automagical"; the only thing that bothers me is that this "automagic" merely doesn't work.
I just fail to understand why there's a need to tmalloc() 22 times more memory than the database itself. This would be a pure academical question if OOM killer wouldn't kill mongod each week.
Using MongoDB:          6.0.5
Using Mongosh:          1.8.0

# free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        4013984     3089660      319744        4784      604580      674440
Swap:             0           0           0

storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  wiredTiger:
    engineConfig:
      cacheSizeGB: 0.5
  journal:
    enabled: true

test> show dbs;
admin     132.00 KiB
config    108.00 KiB
giveback  108.89 MiB
local      80.00 KiB

formattedString: '------------------------------------------------\n' +
'MALLOC:      323286584 (  308.3 MiB) Bytes in use by application\n' +
'MALLOC: +   2224934912 ( 2121.9 MiB) Bytes in page heap freelist\n' +
'MALLOC: +     58162592 (   55.5 MiB) Bytes in central cache freelist\n' +
'MALLOC: +      5434240 (    5.2 MiB) Bytes in transfer cache freelist\n' +
'MALLOC: +    160903336 (  153.4 MiB) Bytes in thread cache freelists\n' +
'MALLOC: +     17039360 (   16.2 MiB) Bytes in malloc metadata\n' +
'MALLOC:   ------------\n' +
'MALLOC: =   2789761024 ( 2660.5 MiB) Actual memory used (physical + swap)\n' +
'MALLOC: +      1675264 (    1.6 MiB) Bytes released to OS (aka unmapped)\n' +
'MALLOC:   ------------\n' +
'MALLOC: =   2791436288 ( 2662.1 MiB) Virtual address space used\n' +
'MALLOC:\n' +
'MALLOC:          30751              Spans in use\n' +
'MALLOC:             80              Thread heaps in use\n' +
'MALLOC:           4096              Tcmalloc page size\n' +
'------------------------------------------------\n' +
'Call ReleaseFreeMemory() to release freelist memory to the OS (via madvise()).\n' +
'Bytes released to the OS take up virtual address space but no physical memory.\n'

